# IntelliJ IDEA OSGi Project Does Not Recognize javax.servlet

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, osgi

I have an OSGi project in IntelliJ, imported from Maven project, which claims that the package javax.servlet.* does not exist.  See screenshot:

[image: IDE Screenshot]

But when I go to Project Structure > Libraries, I clearly see the javax.servlet-api jar.  See screenshot:

[image: Project Settings > Libraries]

How can I resolve this?  TIA!

Comment: Reimport the module after removing it as maven module in the IDEA.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I went to Maven > Remove Module, then Add Maven Module, then Maven > Reimport.  Same issue.